# Validate Html.DropDownListFor, not send detault value when httpPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm having this dropDownListFor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ChoosenThemeSetting, Model.ThemeSettings.Select(k => new SelectListItem { Text = k.ChoosenTheme, Value = k.ChoosenTheme, }), "-- Select here --", new { @class = "form-control", id = "colorIfZero" })
```

In the code I've set "-- Select here --" as the default value. If I don't select anything else than the detault value in my dropDown, the default value will be posted to my [httpPost]-method.

Is there some way to valite this. Like: if selected value is my default value, give me a validation message to choose somthing from my dropDown. Becaues my default "-- Select here --" I would not like to send to my [httpPost]

Comment: check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148038/how-to-set-state-of-dropdownlistfor-default-value/23197318#23197318

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved thank's to this link: http://forums.asp.net/t/1580133.aspx?DropDownListFor+validation. Thank you ravikatha!

By setting the model-class that hold the property for ChoosenThemeSetting to (in the class)

```
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("")]
    public string ChoosenThemeSetting { get; set; }
```

And then change my DropDown-code to this (note the string.empty-line)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ChoosenThemeSetting, Model.ThemeSettings.Select(k => new SelectListItem { Text = k.ChoosenTheme, Value = k.ChoosenTheme, }), string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control", id = "colorIfZero" })
```

And everything works fine!
I now get a validationmessage to chose some of the values from my DropDown

Comment: Of course I don't have to leave the default value as String.Empty.. Changed it to "-- Select here --". And works that as well!